# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error is coming

Tags: .net, newrelic

**Problem Statement**
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

We have written an .NET application which calls New Relic API from our .NET web application.
This code has been working for many years suddenly we started seeing some issues.

**Code Snippet**

**TLS Line**

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

**API Call**
Http response as null url(https://insights-api.newrelic.com/xx/accounts/xxxxxx/query?nrql=)

**Started Observing**

when we run this application locally from our instance it is working fine but whenever we try it from AWS EC2 Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard we started seeing error but noticeably this was working for last 2 years and stopped working for last one week.
Looking for some advise, what are the steps should be taken in order to fix this issue.

We have tested the application locally from our instance it is working fine and fetching data but whenever we try it from AWS EC2 Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard it is giving error saying
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel